# oracle PLS-00103 причина ошибки?

Tags: sql, oracle

Выполняю следующую операцию:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE qwe AS

  TYPE ref_cursor IS REF cursor;

  PROCEDURE get_salary(p_okpo in varchar2,
                                 c_customers out ref_cursor,
                                 p_result out number,
                                 p_result_msg out varchar2);

END qwe;
```

И возникает следую ошибка:

```
1:17:PLS-00103: Встретился символ "" в то время как ожидалось одно из следующих: 
end function package pragma private procedure subtype type 
use <идентификатор> 
<идентификатор с двойными> кавычками-разделителями> form 
current cursor
```

Как ее исправить?

Comment: Попробовал - Package QWE compiled. Где и как вы выполняете запрос?

Comment: @0xdb Это прикол?) имеет значение где выполнять? В intellij idea я делаю

Comment: У меня была похожая ерунда. Правил файл тоже в Идее и в Textmate (на маке). Кто-то из них вставил в начало файла какие-то спецсимволы (два или три), которые многими текстовыми редакторами тупо пропускаются. То есть выглядит текст нормально, а СУБД ругается. Мне помогла линуксовая утилита less (нашел символы и удалил). Попробуйте посмотреть в каком-нибудь hex редакторе. Или попробуйте текст перенабрать в блокноте (если его немного) и сохранить.

Comment: @Dmitry, возможно вы о [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) говорите? Многие редакторы позволяют указать сохранять UTF с BOM или без...

Comment: @MaxU Возможно. Меня тогда мало интересовало конкретное назначение этих двух байтов, гораздо больше волновало то, что из-за них все падало и билось в конвульсиях. Я один раз вырезал и больше эта ерунда не повторялась.

Comment: "имеет значение где выполнять?" - имеет,  у каждого клиента свои особенности. Уберите пустые строки из кода,  возможно поможет.

Comment: @MaxU Человек, который помог разобраться мне с моей проблемой, дал мне эту ссылку: https://habrahabr.ru/post/311518/ Судя по тому, что там пишут, всяких непонятных невидимых символов существует более чем дофига.